# Consolidating Excel files in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have followed online instruction that allow me to do this if all of the files that I need are in the same folder.

Whilst all of the files that I need are indeed in my "Downloads" folder, there are other files in there as well.

Where I am getting lost is in editing my list of the files that I want.

When I press edit it takes me to Power Query (where I can filter the files that I want) but when I press Load and save it just creates a list of those files and doesn't allow me to then combine and edit.

I just end up with a list of the files that I wanted to combine!

Could anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code to combine all XLS files in a directory.  Add your code starting in the third row to further filter the filenames as needed, then let the rest of the steps proceed to combine them

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
// add another filter here as desired
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you work with your info a bit.

To be able to select the files you want to use from the folder, what you want to do is, when you go to get data from folder, click the *Transform Data* button instead of the pre-selected *Combine* or *Combine & Transform Data* button. (Which of the pre-selected buttons you'll see depends upon how you navigated to get data from folder.) After you click the *Transform Data* button, you'll be presented a table of your folder's contents, with various columns of pertinent info. You can then filter based on the info in the columns and, after filtering, you can click on the [image: combine] button to combine the contents of the filtered files.